# How to showmodal a form or getting value from same form in TTabSheet?

Tags: vcl, delphi

I have a form that I display in two different ways. First one is child of TTabSheet in TPageControl. I don't need to collect any data and it works fine.

**First way**

```
  with TTabSheet.Create(APageControl) do
  begin
    PageControl := APageControl;
    Caption := 'Child Form Caption Info';
    APageControl.ActivePageIndex := PageIndex;
  end;

  with TMyDefinitionForm.CreateFor(Application, 'DEF_TYPE', 'Child Form Caption Info') do
  begin
    Parent := APageControl.Pages[APageControl.ActivePageIndex];
    Align := alClient;
    Name := 'ChildFormName';
    Show;
  end;
```

Second one is creating by different detail form and should be returned some needed values from same form. But when I create this form as first one, I can't display form as **ShowModal** in TTabSheet. *(It can't be active or focused)*

**Second way**

```
var
  AComponent: TComponent;
begin
{This is different detail form and its owner is DashboardForm which has TPageControl}
  AComponent := (Self.Owner.FindComponent('APageControl') as TPageControl); 

  with TTabSheet.Create(AComponent) do
  begin
    PageControl := (AComponent as TPageControl);
    Caption := 'Child Form Caption Info';
    (AComponent as TPageControl).ActivePageIndex := PageIndex;
  end;

  with TMyDefinitionForm.CreateFor(Self, 'DEF_TYPE', 'Child Form Caption Info') do
  begin
    Parent := (AComponent as TPageControl).Pages[(AComponent as TPageControl).ActivePageIndex];
    Name := 'ChildFormName';
    Show; { If I change this to ShowModal, I can't click to my form }
  end;

  txtFieldOne.Text := DataModuleObject.Field; {sample usage}
  txtFieldTwo.Text := DataModuleObject.Field2; {sample usage}
  SomeVariables:= DataModuleObject.Field3; {sample usage}
end;
```

**Problem**: I have a DataModule that has data objects for general usage. When I create this child form, I have to set some value to those objects and after closing child form, those data should be set to my first form. To do this, I always used ShowModal, then in next lines I set those values to my first form. But now I can't open ShowModal in TTabSheet.

**Question**: Is there any way to get those values from child form?

**Bonus Question**: I can use ShowModal then I can get those values, if I just create that form. Should I create form as normal in TTabSheet without set the Parent Control?

*Note: using XE10.1 Berlin*

Comment: Modal form must be a top level window. What modality means is that you aren't allowed to interact with anything else whole the modal window is active. That can't be readily achieved in a page control. You'd have to disable every other page and every other control on the form hosting the page control. You need a better understanding of modality before you design your UI.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Thank you for rapid answering. I'm not expert in VCL, this is why I can't figure out this situation. What do you suggest me to solve this problem quickly? or do you have any idea for transfering data from different form in VCL?

Comment: Why do you want to solve the problem quickly? Some problems aren't solved quickly. Some problems require time, effort and understanding? Why do you belittle the skills required to develop software?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan You are right. Do you know where I lookup for understanding desktop application development fundamentals and requirements?

Comment: Well, I like Alan Cooper's About Face